# How can I see total time today on _all projects_ in the modeline?

Tags: org-mode, mode-line

The variable `org-clock-modeline-total` gives me several options for what time to show in the modeline, but they limited to time clocked into the current task. I would like to show the total time clock into all tasks in a particular subtree. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

The org-mode function `org-clock-sum-today` comes pretty close to doing what you want; I found it while digging around in `org-clock.el`  One option would be to write a wrapper function around that, then add the wrapper function to your mode line.  For example:

```
(defun saintaardvark-org-clock-todays-total ()
  "Display total minutes clocked into org-mode for today."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (set-buffer "test.org")
    (format " Today's total: %s " (org-minutes-to-clocksum-string (org-clock-sum-today)))))
```

After that, you can customize `mode-line-format` and insert something like this:

```
(:eval
  (saintaardvark-org-clock-todays-total))
```

On my machine, that gives me a mode line like this:

[image: Mode line showing "Total Time"]

There are a couple things to note about this:

- The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data) for the `:eval` form says "Make sure this evaluation cannot load any files, as doing so could cause infinite recursion."  I presume this means it shouldn't load any other elisp files, and that a `save-excursion` is okay...but I could be wrong about this.
- This does not turn off org-mode's own mode display.
- You might want to suggest this feature (showing today's total) as an enhancement to the org-mode project.
- This function assumes that everything is in one org file.
- Up until relatively recently, I *think* there was a bug in org-clock-sum-today; it takes `headline-filter` as an argument (which would allow you to get total time by subtree), but did not actually use it.  This [appears to be fixed](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-clock.el#n1729) in HEAD in the Git repo, but is not in the latest released version (8.2.10).