# how to get today's total logged time programatically?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to set the title of my emacs to how much work I've done in total.

I would like to get the time I've logged today programatically. (like when you open agenda and press 'R'). How do I do that?

I tried:  [(as per this link)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-can-i-see-total-time-today-on-all-projects-in-the-modeline)

```
(format " Today's total: %s " (org-minutes-to-clocksum-string (org-clock-sum-today)))
```

But that returns 0:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org-clock-sum-today` only gets clock data from the buffer that Emacs is currently visiting, `(set-buffer "test.org")` in the linked example.  I came up with this based on `org-dblock-write:clocktable` in `org-clock`, maybe it will work for you?

```
(defun eqyiel-org-clock-sum-today ()
  "Visit each file in `org-agenda-files' and return the total time of today's
clocked tasks in minutes."
  (let ((files (org-agenda-files))
        (total 0))
    (org-agenda-prepare-buffers files)
    (dolist (file files)
      (with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting file)
        (setq total (+ total (org-clock-sum-today)))))
    total))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!.  This lags a bit when it runs, so I made a little function that runs this in the background once a minute and caches it's output.